Is there a function for how hot an object would have to be to compensate for the drop off after SSR is exceeded using a microbolometer?
I am wondering if there is a clean formula for how much hotter a given object would have to be to register at the same temperature after the spot-size ratio has been diminished for a given thermal camera. We can assume a black body and a constant ambient at room temperature. Would it be as simple as averaging the total temperature so that if an object only encompassed 1/4 of the pixel, it would have to be 4x greater than the difference between the ambient and the registered temperature, or am I missing something?
